# How to correct Google Earth's "invalid HTTP request" notice?

Tags: 12.04, google-earth, https

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. As you might know Google Earth 7 doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.04 yet.

I installed Google Earth via `make-googleearth-package --force` command. My installation was successful. At the beginning everything was working fine. But after some days I had a problem. When I type in "Fly to" box a city I wanted to search for it. It gives me "invalid HTTP request" error as seen in the picture:

[image: Google-Earth picture]

How to solve?

P.S: I removed and reinstalled it but problem still persists. I can search globe via mouse only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is due to an old [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) version, that seems to cause the trouble. If you already have libcurl on your system (and I am pretty sure Ubuntu 12.04 has), you can simply rename the libcurl coming with Google Earth like this:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/googleearth/libcurl.so.4 /usr/lib/googleearth/backup_libcurl.so.4
```

And the problem should be gone (the path in my Linux Mint and probably other distributions is `/opt/google/earth/free/libcurl.so.4`).

Comment: This also solved the same issue on Fedora 18 withgoogleearth 6.0.3 (except the earth version of libcurl was in a slightly different place - /usr/lib/googleearth/libcurl.so.4)
THanks

Comment: Doesn't work. stiil waiting an answer. Thank you. @bytefish

Comment: That surprises me. Which curl version is Ubuntu 12.04 shipped with?

Comment: that worked for me on LMDE UP6

Comment: Thanks Andy Paterson. I tried the same solution as you mentioned for Fedora ( /usr/lib/googleearth/libcurl.so.4 ) it worked like a charm for my Ubuntu 12.04 distro. @AndyPaterson

Answer (score 1):

I suddenly started seeing this error after running several updates. I tried a number of things unsuccessfully and finally updated GE to 7.1 - it couldn't hurt. Problem went bye bye! I hope this works for you.

Comment: This worked for me too. Reminds me that sometimes manually installed programs need to be updated.